# Can DVD be used after it stuck at 100% Creating image checksum when burning?

Tags: windows, dvd

I've a DVD+R (btw, I don't know why I can't add files to it and it's +R and not -R) and I tried to Burn Windows Starter on it (I need it for something), but the problem is that burning stuck at 100% Creating image checksum. so I rebooted the system (from Terminal).

Now, can this DVD be used to install Windows Starter without problems? and Can I know if a DVD is missing a file or a system will have problems when installed?

Answer (score 0):

The cd, if bootable, could still be used to install.

I wouldn't recommend tho, the system may fail because the cd wasn't finished. The best to do it to burn it again (or make a bootable usb, that's a better option). If the cd wasn't finished it may not contain all files necessary to the system run properly.